# What's the difference between __raw_writel, writel_relaxed and writel in linux kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

What's the difference between __raw_writel, writel_relaxed and writel in linux kernel? When should I use writel_relaxed and __raw_writel?

Comment: Yes, there is difference. Check their implementations to get an answer. **TL;DR** `writel()` -- write to the *little-endian* hardware register with *compiler memory barrier*, `writel_relaxed` -- as above, **without** *barrier*, `__raw_writel()` -- as above (`writel_relaxed()`) **without** *endianess* conversion (CPU ordering will be used). Be careful, those are **architecture-dependent**.

Comment: Adding to @0andriy comment, consider using `iowrite32()` and friends. Also look into [chapter 9.4](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4) of LDD3 book.

Comment: @SamProtsenko, `iowriteXXbe()` makes sense, otherwise it's just an additional check for address space, I'm not sure there are plenty of hardware that using IO ports instead of MMIO nowadays.

Comment: @0andriy On most architectures `iowrite32()` just turns to `writel()`, indeed. It's just a recommended API, doesn't mean it's somehow superior to `writel()`. I just don't really like `l` suffix, means `long`, which was ok for 16-bit architecture, and for 32 bit+ architecture it doesn't have much sense (32 bit variable is just a word, not a long word). So it's better to use something like `32` as API suffixes.

Comment: The link to chapter 9.4 in the comment above is broken. It can be accessed from archive.org, though, at http://web.archive.org/web/20170624191512/http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-9-sect-4 (BTW, @0andriy, your comments are really the answer, right? Why not submit as such?)

Comment: @nillab, it’s just a tip of iceberg, the real answer would be several times longer. And tbh I’m too lazy to go through the code again, there are changes happened due to security (?) reason, and something happened to 64 bit ops. This what I saw in mailing list for last few months. It might be more changes done recently.